# How do I fix value cannot be null Parameter name: typeName when opening XAML file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, xaml

We are using Silverlight 4 (we must use it. :p ) with VS2010. AFAIK we have the proper toolkits and SDKs installed.

When we try to open a XAML file, we are immediately presented with an error dialog that says: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: typeName". The designer does not load. There is no output in the output window, there are no build errors.

We are at a complete loss on what to do.

This does only affect some of our workstations. We are in a controlled enviorment and reinstalling VS2010 is not really an option. Again :p

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: How do I get a stack trace? This a modal dialog, the XAML never makes it into design mode. Can I still get a trace?

Comment: Are you defining your parameter as a static user resource ?

Comment: That's the thing, I am not defining this parameter. Interestingly, it works on some workstations and not others. Same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue specific to our corporate environment. MS support has been helping us for several days now. They don't seem any closer to a solution than we were.

Good luck to anyone here with the same question.

Comment: This is the saddest SO entry I have ever made. :'(

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar dialog boxes pop up when I have had reference issues in the xaml but not with that exact text. I would verify that all the refferences are in the correct location and that they are the correct version.